# Intellij New Maven Java Project from BitBucket not recognized as Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I created New Project from Git ( BitBucket ) in IntelliJ, I got particular branch from Repository. I assigned specific SDK to the project however IntelliJ is not recognizing it as Maven project. I can't get to the classes definitions, don't get prompts when importing etc etc.

IntelliJ treats *.java files as plain text files rather than classes. Is there some sort of setting I am missing?

Comment: What happens if you type "mvn package" at the command line?

Comment: Please share the screenshot of whole IDe window. Most probably, it is needed to mark `src` folder as sources in context menu

Comment: @tgdavies, Maven installation is missing, I am going to have it soon and then check again

Comment: UPDATE : After Maven installation I added it to the Project ( there was a prompt ) and it's fine now. I just need to go through the dependencies and fix the errors.